# Reboot a Chromecast

Tags: java, android, google-play, chromecast

How can I, using the Cast SDK or otherwise, have my app trigger a Chromecast reboot, in the manner of the official Chromecast app?

In the case of 'otherwise', is Google Play likely to look unkindly on this approach?

Comment: Why do you need to reboot the chromecast? That might be something users don't like and it isn't a common behaviour of chromecast-enabled apps.

Comment: I'm writing an app called Reboot My Chromecast.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API in the SDK to reboot a Cast device and frankly, it is scary to me that you would want to do that programmatically. What is the reason you would want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should be able to. It's just a HTTP post after all. [This from pychromecast](https://github.com/balloob/pychromecast)

```
CC_SESSION.post(FORMAT_BASE_URL.format(host) + "/setup/reboot", data='{"params":"now"}', timeout=10)
```

That might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Following on the answer from davewasthere (thanks!), I found that I can reboot a Chromecast by performing the following command from Linux prompt:

```
curl -Lv -H Content-Type:application/json \
--data-raw '{"params":"now"}' \
http://10.10.2.49:8008/setup/reboot
```

[Some other useful DIAL commands](http://fiquett.com/2013/07/chromecast-traffic-sniffing/)

Answer (score 0):

A recent firmware update seems to have disabled the HTTP endpoint on port `8008` (`HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`) so the [solution posted by norganna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271464/370252) does not work any longer.

Working alternative is the HTTPS endpoint on port `8443`:

```
curl -Lv --insecure -H Content-Type:application/json --data-raw '{"params":"now"}' https://10.10.2.49:8443/setup/reboot
```

Comment: Seems like the latest Chromecast update is now blocking this method as well.